# Custom theme not appearing in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, wordpress-theming

So I'm taking the advice I get every time I ask any other questions about WordPress: learning to develop my own theme so that I can understand the WP codebase better. I have fallen at the first hurdle.

I'm following the freecodecamp.org video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h7gOJbIpmo&t=351s and when I get to the point where his theme appears as an option in wp-admin, my theme does not. I have also tried creating another theme with only what is required to create a theme according to the WP codex, index.php and style.css with the required comments, and this still doesn't show up.

I am hosting using the most up-to-date version of Local on OSX, this is the only thing I can think of that might be different from the example in the tutorial but he doesn't cover the hosting side of his set-up.

Even after I delete the themes that were prepackaged with the installation, 2019, 2020, 2021, they still show up in wp-admin. I have restarted Local and it still finds the themes that don't exist in the directory.

Where could I be going wrong???

Comment: Could you paste the contents of your style.css and index.php here? I'm guessing there's an issue with how those files are formatted. Also, making sure you definitely are saving your theme as a folder within wp-content/themes/your-folder-name-here. I've done this before :)

Comment: /*
Theme name: intelrise
Text domain: intelrise
Version: 1.0
Description: Fancy theme with left sidebar
Tags: left-sidebar, responsive, fancy
Author: Benny Green
Author URI: https://bennygreen.ca
*/

Comment: that's the style.css, the index.php is empty. I have verified the path but I suspect this is the issue. I have installed another theme that I use via wp-admin and it installs fine but isn't showing in the themes directory

Comment: Is this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your style.css posted above, you need to capitalize "name" in "Theme Name: intelrise"

WordPress is picky about that :)

Comment: I made the change and still no luck

Comment: Hmmm... Actually.. Rereading your comment about deleting the 2020 etc themes, and they're still there. I'm starting to wonder if you might be in the wrong directory? Is that possible? Or if Local is looking in the wrong spot for the site you're trying to access?